# How can I make repeated use of a same feature described in cucumber feature file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, pageobjects, cucumber-java

Iam checking a profile adding page, once a user is added the profile it has to be approved by another user. So first I have to login as a user(A) and add the profile after that I have to log in as User(B) to approve the added profile.

How can i use the same login details added in the feature file for logging in for the second user.

Feature file snippet is given below,

```
Given enter '<Username>' and '<Password>'   
When clicking submit button
Then System should log into application and prompt msg as<Msg>
Examples:
|Username|Password|
|test    |test@1  |
```

The login credentials for second user is

```
|Username|Password|
|test    |test@1  |
```

How can I use the details for the first user to login second user.
Please help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident that whether I understand your question clearly or not? As per my understanding you want to use same login details for 2 different cases.

Your test scenario:

1. Login as UserA
2. Add Profile
3. Login as UserB
4. Approve Profile

Feature File should be:

```
Background: Login 
When clicking submit button
Then System should log into application and prompt msg as<Msg>
Examples:
|Username|Password|
|test    |test@1  |
```

Scenario: Add profile
When click on 'Add Profile' button and fill details
Then Submit profile details

Scenario: Approve Profile
Given navigate to approve profile page
Then click on approve button

Please update me if it helps